# php uniqid with smaller value in ascending order

Tags: php

in a folder named `images` i have images like this:

```
5ac7d5f6b23d3.jpg
```

the names are given using php `uniqid` function and the folder `images` is sorted by name - ascending

now I'm creating a new image

is there a way - `using uniqid or any other function` - to give the name of a new image - so it is the `first` - in ascending order ?

so getting names using

```
$array = glob('images/*.jpg');
print_r($array);
```

the new image should be the first in array

Comment: Prepend image filenames with a sort prefix, eg. `00000001_`, `00000002_` etc… The `uniqid` function supports a prefix parameter.

Comment: You can sort by mtime (modification time) using [DirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)

Comment: @MarkusZeller - do you mean - first sort the folder `images` by modification time descending and then go to `glob...`

Comment: No, don't use glob at all. When you have all values and ordered by mtime descending, then you already have the newest file which is then the first entry. The iterator extends SplFileInfo which gives you very detailed information of any file.

Comment: could you write an example, pls - I need array of files sorted by date descending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) can be used to scan all files of a Directory and read the mtime (modification time) of each file. Storing them into an array as key, we can sort the keys descending to get the newest file.

> This will find any files, because no glob pattern is used here. You could also rewrite using [GlobIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.globiterator.php), if a pattern is required.

Now let's scan the directory for all files and ignore another directories.

```
$mtimes = [];
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('./images') as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDir()) continue;
    $mtimes[$fileInfo->getMTime()] = $fileInfo->getFilename();
}
```

Sort the array by keys in reverse (descending)

```
krsort($mtimes);
```

Grab the first element which is the newest file.

```
$latestFilename = reset($mtimes);
```

Comment: and where is the array of files?

Comment: `$mtimes` does contains all files. You can go thru all with `foreach ($mtimes as $mtime => $filename) echo "$filename last modified at $mtime\n";`